# My HTML game is not running, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote this game from a tutorial i read online, it was working just fine, until i messed it up, my developer tools console says theres a reference error but i just cant see it, please help, the error i get through my we developer console is "Uncaught ReferenceError: Draw is not defined(anonymous function) @ games.html:228 "

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Gamedev Canvas Workshop</title>
        <style>
            * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
            canvas { background: #eee; 
            display: block; 
            margin: 0 auto; 
            }
            #checking {
            margin-left:650px;
            }
            #checking1 {
            margin-left:650px;
            }
            #checking2 {
            margin-left:650px;
            }
            #checking3 {
            margin-left:650px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
        <br/>
        <div id ="checking">Current Position</div>
        <div id ="checking1">Nothings Moving Bro</div>
        <br/>
        <div id ="checking3">Color State</div>
        <div id ="checking2">Nope, still nothing</div>
        <script>
            // JavaScript code goes here
               var checking1 = document.getElementById("checking1");
               var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
               var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

               var x = canvas.width/2;
               var y = canvas.height-30;
               var ballRadius = 20;  
               var dx = 2;
               var dy = -2;
               var paddleheight = 10;
               var paddlewidth = 50;
               var paddleX = (canvas.height - paddlewidth)/2;
               var RightKeyPressed = false;
               var LeftKeyPressed = false;


               document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler,false);
               document.addEventListener("keyup",keyUpHandler,false);


               function keyDownHandler(e){

                   if(e.keycode == 39){

                       RightKeyPressed = true;


                   }else if(e.keycode == 37){

                       LeftKeyPressed = true;


                   } 
               }


               function keyUpHandler(e){

                   if(e.keycode == 39){


                       RightKeyPressed = false;



                   }else if(e.keycode == 37){

                       LeftKeyPressed = false;


                   }    

                function randomInt(min,max){

                       return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min))+ min; }


               function paddle(){

                   ctx.beginPath;
                   ctx.rect(paddleX,canvas.height - paddleheight,paddlewidth,paddleheight);
                   ctx.fillStyle="#0095DD";
                   ctx.fill();
                   ctx.closePath;






               }


               function drawball(){
                    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x,y,ballRadius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,149,221)";
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.closePath();




                 }


               function Draw(){

                   ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);


                   drawball();
                  paddle();









                   if(y + dy > canvas.height - 20 || y + dy < ballRadius){


                       var cx =  randomInt(0,255);
                       var cy = randomInt(0,255);
                       var cz = randomInt(0,255);


                           ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(cx,cy,cz)";
                           ctx.fill();



                       dy = -dy;



                   }



               if ( x + dx > canvas.width - 20  || x + dx < ballRadius){


                   var cx =  randomInt(0,255);
                       var cy = randomInt(0,255);
                       var cz = randomInt(0,255);


                           ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(cx,cy,cz)";
                           ctx.fill();  


                   dx = -dx; }



                    x += dx;
                    y += dy

                    var color = ctx.fillStyle;
                    checking1.innerHTML = " x: " + x + "y: " + y ;
                    checking2.innerHTML = color ;


               }







               }


               if(RightKeyPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - 50 ){

                   paddleX += 7;

               }else if(LeftKeyPressed && paddleX > 0){

                   paddleX -= 7;







               }


               setInterval(Draw,10);






        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the url of the tutorial ?

Comment: I pasted your code into a text editor and I can only see 221 lines. Can you clarify which line you have the error on?

Answer (score 4):

Your code throws the error because it cannot find the function `Draw()`:

```
setInterval(Draw, 10);
```

This is because your function is not in the same scope. Your code structure is like this:

```
function keyUpHandler(e) {
   ...
   function Draw(){
      //Codes here
   }
   ...
}
...
setInterval(Draw, 10);
```

Since the `Draw()` function is inside the `keyUpHandler(e)`, it cannot be seen from any outside function (that is functions that are on a higher level/scope).

Hope this clears your mind :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to close your keyuphandler function (currently you have like 3 function inside it until you finally close it at line 193).

add a function closure at about line 88 to close your keyuphandler.

Than you have a extra function closure at line 193 remove that and it works

(by function closure i mean brackets {}  )

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d74tk3we/) , you closing bracket of  function  keyDownHandlercode is wrong

```
 var checking1 = document.getElementById("checking1");
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 var x = canvas.width / 2;
 var y = canvas.height - 30;
 var ballRadius = 20;
 var dx = 2;
 var dy = -2;
 var paddleheight = 10;
 var paddlewidth = 50;
 var paddleX = (canvas.height - paddlewidth) / 2;
 var RightKeyPressed = false;
 var LeftKeyPressed = false;


 document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
 document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);


 function keyDownHandler(e) {

     if (e.keycode == 39) {

         RightKeyPressed = true;


     } else if (e.keycode == 37) {

         LeftKeyPressed = true;


     }
 }


 function keyUpHandler(e) {

     if (e.keycode == 39) {


         RightKeyPressed = false;



     } else if (e.keycode == 37) {

         LeftKeyPressed = false;


     }
 }
     function randomInt(min, max) {

         return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
     }


     function paddle() {

         ctx.beginPath;
         ctx.rect(paddleX, canvas.height - paddleheight, paddlewidth, paddleheight);
         ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
         ctx.fill();
         ctx.closePath;
     }


     function drawball() {
         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
         ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,149,221)";
         ctx.fill();
         ctx.closePath();
     }

     function zan(){
     alert('test');
     }

     function Draw() {

         ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
         drawball();
         paddle();
         if (y + dy > canvas.height - 20 || y + dy < ballRadius) {
             var cx = randomInt(0, 255);
             var cy = randomInt(0, 255);
             var cz = randomInt(0, 255);
             ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(cx,cy,cz)";
             ctx.fill();
             dy = -dy;
         }
         if (x + dx > canvas.width - 20 || x + dx < ballRadius) {
             var cx = randomInt(0, 255);
             var cy = randomInt(0, 255);
             var cz = randomInt(0, 255);
             ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(cx,cy,cz)";
             ctx.fill();
             dx = -dx;
         }
         x += dx;
         y += dy

         var color = ctx.fillStyle;
         checking1.innerHTML = " x: " + x + "y: " + y;
         checking2.innerHTML = color;
     }



 if (RightKeyPressed && paddleX < canvas.width - 50) {
     paddleX += 7;
 } else if (LeftKeyPressed && paddleX > 0) {
     paddleX -= 7;
 }

 setInterval(Draw, 10);
```